# Equal height for 2 plots in ggarrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

For simplicity here is a runnable code with fake data that produces the issue exactly. The plots,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

data1 <- data.frame(
  V1=replicate(18, {sample(1:18, 1)}),
  V2=replicate(18, {sample(1:3, 1)}),
  V3=replicate(18, {sample(1:3, 1)})
)

graph1 <- ggplot(data1, aes(x=V1, y=V2, fill=V3))+geom_tile(size=0.5)+coord_equal()

data2 <- data.frame(
  V1=replicate(18, {sample(1:3, 1)}),
  V2=replicate(18, {sample(1:3, 1)})
)
graph2 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x=c("A"), y=V1,fill=V2))+geom_tile(size=0.5)+coord_equal()

ggarrange(graph1, graph2, labels = c("A", "B"), ncol = 2, nrow = 1)
```

generate,

[image]

and as you can see the first plot shrinks because its too large. **How do I prevent the first graph from shrinking even if that will produce a very large in width image?**

Note that the result is similar to what is produced when running `ggarrange` with `nrow=5` but if I do that then the graph is flat and all other elements look weird:

[image]

Using `widths` as suggested in one answer generates:

[image]

Which have different heights. *I assume* it may look just fine on some screens settings. **How can I ensure that both plots always have the same height no matter the viewport size?**

Answer (score 2):

One option is to specify the relative widths of each figure, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
data1 <- data.frame(
  V1=replicate(18, {sample(1:18, 1)}),
  V2=replicate(18, {sample(1:3, 1)}),
  V3=replicate(18, {sample(1:3, 1)})
)

graph1 <- ggplot(data1, aes(x=V1, y=V2, fill=V3))+geom_tile(size=0.5)+coord_equal()

data2 <- data.frame(
  V1=replicate(18, {sample(1:3, 1)}),
  V2=replicate(18, {sample(1:3, 1)})
)
graph2 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x=c("A"), y=V1,fill=V2))+geom_tile(size=0.5)+coord_equal()

ggarrange(graph1, graph2, labels = c("A", "B"), ncol = 2, nrow = 1, widths = c(0.85, 0.15))
```

You can specify the dimensions when you save the plot:

```
ggsave(filename = "example.png", width = 12, height = 3, units = "in")
```

[image: example2.png]

**EDIT**
In an RMarkdown file, you can also specify fig.height and fig.width to alter the dimensions of the final figure, e.g.

````
> ---
> title: "test"
> author: "test"
> date: "11/12/2020"
> output: html_document
> ---
> 
> ```{r setup, include=FALSE} knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE) ```
> 
> ```{r plot, fig.height=3, fig.width=12}
> library(tidyverse)
> library(ggpubr)
> data1 <- data.frame(   V1=replicate(18, {sample(1:18,
> 1)}),   V2=replicate(18, {sample(1:3, 1)}),   V3=replicate(18,
> {sample(1:3, 1)}) )
> 
> graph1 <- ggplot(data1, aes(x=V1, y=V2,
> fill=V3))+geom_tile(size=0.5)+coord_equal()
> 
> data2 <- data.frame(   V1=replicate(18, {sample(1:3, 1)}),  
> V2=replicate(18, {sample(1:3, 1)}) ) graph2 <- ggplot(data2,
> aes(x=c("A"), y=V1,fill=V2))+geom_tile(size=0.5)+coord_equal()
> 
> ggarrange(graph1, graph2, labels = c("A", "B"), ncol = 2, nrow = 1,
> widths = c(0.85, 0.15))
> ```
````

[image: rmarkdown_example.png]

Comment: Thanks however it only looks correct in the png file. Is there a way to make it look like that in all cases?

Comment: Yes, in R studio the heights don't match. I suppose even the screen size has some effect s on how it looks.

Comment: I've updated the good effort put into your answer but I am definitively looking for a solution that requires no resizing since the final outcome will be a Knit'ed HTML document. I can't count on the final user resizing the graph. Is there any other solution to keeping the heights equal at all times?

Comment: Hey @adelriosantiago, does my edited answer solve your problem?

Comment: Tried it, no luck! I think we have different screen configurations. In mine looks like the image I posted in the answer. On the phone it looks a bit better for some reason. Really strange.

Comment: Sorry @adelriosantiago, I am out of ideas - feel free to delete the question and repost to try and attract a better answer. It would be great to use some of your actual data if possible. Sorry I couldn't help more

Comment: No worries! This was a good answer. In fact it is currently the best option I have, and what I am currently using. Let's keep everything as is and see if there is an improvement over the current strategy in the future. Thanks!